# How to connect XML data contained in Window.Resources in XAML file to XML.Linq

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, xaml

I have put XML data which represents the NATO phonetic alphabet into XAML window File. I have also code behind which I want to generate programatically Stack Panels per Entry which will contain 2 labels each, One containing the Letter and second the Phonetic word representing it. It will all be put in a wrap panel. I could have done a lot less just making the xaml manually but this is practice, and I really want to checkout Linq and XML. The code behind contains all the comments. This is my first time using Linq and XML in code so I don't really know what I am doing so Please explain the concepts and add links and not only answers.

Here is the XAML:

```
<!--The XML database of letter of the phonetic alphabet this will be moved to seprate file-->
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="PhoneticAlphabet" XPath="Alphabet/Entries" >
        <x:XData>
            <Alphabet xmlns="">
                <Entries>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Aa</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Alpha</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Bb</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Bravo</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Cc</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Charlie</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Dd</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Delta</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Ee</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Echo</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Ff</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Foxtrot</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Gg</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Golf</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Hh</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Hotel</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Ii</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>India</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Jj</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Juliett</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Kk</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Kilo</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Ll</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Lima</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Mm</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Mike</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Nn</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>November</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Oo</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Oscar</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Pp</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Papa</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Qq</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Quebec</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Rr</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Romeo</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Ss</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Sierra</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Tt</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Tango</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Uu</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Uniform</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Vv</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Victor</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Ww</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Whiskey</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Xx</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Xray</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Yy</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Yankee</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                    <Entry>
                        <Letter>Zz</Letter>
                        <Phonetic>Zulu</Phonetic>
                    </Entry>
                </Entries>
            </Alphabet>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource PhoneticAlphabet}"
           XPath="*"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel x:Name="MainPanel">
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
public partial class PhoneticAlphabetWindow : Window
{
    public PhoneticAlphabetWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void setControls() {
        //Get XML data
        //For ech xml Entry
        //Make a stack Panel
        //Make two labels with letter and phonetic and add them to stack panel
        //Add a style to label
        //add a content to be letter
        //make a label with phonetic word
        //addd a style to label
        //add a phonetic           
    }

    private IEnumerable<XElement> getData(String xml) {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> childList =
        from el in doc.Elements()
        select el;
        return childList;
    }

    private void addLabels(StackPanel EntryPanel, String letter, String phonetic) {
        Label letterLabel = new Label();
        letterLabel.Content = letter;

        Label phoneticLabel = new Label();
        phoneticLabel.Content = phonetic;

        EntryPanel.Children.Add(letterLabel);
        EntryPanel.Children.Add(phoneticLabel);
    }

    private StackPanel addStackPanel() {
        StackPanel EntryPanel = new StackPanel();
        EntryPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        MainPanel.Children.Add(EntryPanel);
        return EntryPanel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this link, it should be easy to adapt the code to you XAML XML:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/query-an-xml-document-using-linq-to-xml/

Comment: So i guess the only way to do this then XML is in Window.Resource is to set the XMLDataProvider, set xpath and then use the xpath in the LINQ? Is there not some other way? Is ti just easier to put the data into seprate XML file, and user pure XML LINQ?